# How can I release static internal IP address which I reserved by mistake?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I would like to create new instance on Google Cloud Compute Engine with static **external** IP, but I create new static **internal** IP by mistake as below photo.

[static internal IP at Create an instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0ZBb.png)

Could you tell me how to release it?

Comment: Please view the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page to see why this question is off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **static internal IP addresses** can be deleted by using several methods, such as the VM instances page, the `gcloud` tool or sending a `DELETE` API call, as mentioned in the [Deleting a static internal IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address#deleting_a_static_internal_ip_address) public documentation. Based on this, I suggest you to follow one of the options listed below, as well as take a look on [this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#assign_new_instance), to know more about the process required to assign a **static external IP address** to a new VM instance.

**Console**

1. Go to the [VM instances page](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances?_ga=2.118614281.-1045016555.1526489174).
2. Select your project.
3. Select the **VM instance** from the project list.
4. Select the Edit tool at the top of the page.
5. Click the edit tool for **Network Interfaces**.
6. Change the **Internal IP type** from Static to Ephemeral.
7. Select Release to release your **static IP address**.
8. Click Done to save your changes.

**Gcloud tool**

Using the gcloud tool, run the compute addresses delete command:

- gcloud compute addresses delete **[ADDRESS_NAME]** --region **[REGION]**

**API**

In the API, make a `DELETE` request to the following **URL**:

- `DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/regions/[REGION]/addresses/[ADDRESS_NAME]`

Comment: If you've mistakenly reserved the static internal IP but haven't yet created the VM instance - as of July 2021, the console approach does not work (no release option) -  use the gcloud tool approach instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it on the Console by followed steps:

1. Go to the [VPC Network page](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/networks/list)
2. Click **External IP Addresses** in the left of navigation
3. The ip being released should be on the page. Select ip(s) you want release,  then click **Release** on the top of page.